# Display the cleaning data in the next html page after scraping

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

I want to link the python file and html page using flask application. The first page (upload.html page), the user need to select job field and job title from two dropdown menu. Then, the user need to upload the file that contains list of URLs that will be scraped using automation coding after the user click the button upload. The problem is I only success to display the data that have been not clean.

Here is the following code for HTML code snippet for upload page ad display page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>UPLOAD FILE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper2">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">UPLOAD FILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DETAILS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CLASSIFICATION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SHORTLISTED</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ANALYSIS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="job">
            <h2>Choose job's field: </h2>
            <select name="job-field" id="job-field">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select field</option>
            </select>
              <br><br>
            <h2>Choose job's title: </h2>
            <select name="job-title" id="job-title">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select title</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="upload">
            <h2>Upload a CSV file: </h2>
            <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="file" name="file">
              <br><br>
              <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Scraped Information</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">UPLOAD FILE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DETAILS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CLASSIFICATION</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SHORTLISTED</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ANALYSIS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1>{{ job_field }}</h1>
    {% if job_field == 'IT' %}
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Job's Title</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Experiences</th>
          <th>Education</th>
          <th>Certifications</th>
          <th>Skills</th>
          <th>Languages</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Senior FrontEnd Developer</td>
          <td>No specific</td>
          <td>No specific</td>
          <td>Bachelor Degree in Software Engineering, Computer Science or equivalent</td>
          <td>No specific</td>
          <td>html,css,sass,js,gulp,webpack,jquery,vuejs,vuex,inertiajs,laravel,php,</td>
          <td>No specific</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    {% elif job_field == 'DM' %}
    <p>Details for Digital Marketing go here...</p>
    {% elif job_field == 'FN' %}
    <p>Details for Finance go here...</p>
    {% endif %}

    <h2>Scraped Information</h2>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Experiences</th>
          <th>Education</th>
          <th>Certifications</th>
          <th>Skills</th>
          <th>Languages</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for item in data %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item["Name"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ item["Title"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ item["Location"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ item["Experiences"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ item["Education"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ item["Certifications"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ item["Skills"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ item["Languages"] }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the coding for flask application:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import pandas as pd
from scraper import scrape_data
from data_cleaning import clean_data

app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'static'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home_page.html')

@app.route('/upload_page')
def upload_page():
    return render_template('upload_page.html')

@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    job_field = request.form['job_field']
    return redirect(url_for('display', job_field=job_field))

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    data = scrape_data(df)
    cleandata = clean_data(data)
    return render_template('display.html', data=cleandata)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the coding for scraping:

```
def scrape_data(df):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    sleep(2)
    url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/login'
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(2)

    # Task 1.2: Import username and password
    username = "rinarinza@gmail.com"
    password = "Zahra2011"
    print('- Finish importing the login credentials')
    sleep(2)

    # Task 1.2: Key in login credentials
    email_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username')
    email_field.send_keys(username)

    password_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'session_password')
    password_field.send_keys(password)
    sleep(2)

    # Task 1.2: Click the Login button
    signin_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@type="submit"]')
    signin_field.click()
    sleep(3)
    df.to_csv('mydata.csv', index=False)
    data = []
    with open('mydata.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for url in csvreader:
            # Task 1: Login to Linkedin
            # sleep(2)
            profile_url = url[0]
            driver.get(profile_url)
            start = time.time()
            initialScroll = 0
            finalScroll = 1000

            while True:
                driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo({initialScroll},{finalScroll})")
                # this command scrolls the window starting from the pixel value stored in the initialScroll
                # variable to the pixel value stored at the finalScroll variable
                initialScroll = finalScroll
                finalScroll += 1000

                # we will stop the script for 3 seconds so that the data can load
                time.sleep(2)
                end = time.time()
                # We will scroll for 20 seconds.
                if round(end - start) > 20:
                    break

            src = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
            # print(soup.prettify())

            # 1 NAME
            intro = soup.find('div', {'class': 'pv-text-details__left-panel'})
            name_loc = intro.find("h1")
            name = name_loc.get_text().strip()

            # Title
            title = soup.find('div', {"class": "text-body-medium break-words"}).get_text().replace('\n', '').strip()

            # 2 LOCATION
            loc = soup.find('span', {'class': 'text-body-small inline t-black--light break-words'})
            location = loc.get_text().strip()

            # 3 EXPERIENCE
            experiences = []
            try:
                experience_div = soup.find('div', {"id": "experience"})
                exp_list = experience_div.findNext('div').findNext('div', {"class": "pvs-list__outer-container"}).findChild(
                    'ul').findAll('li',
                                  {"class": "artdeco-list__item pvs-list__item--line-separated pvs-list__item--one-column"})

                for each_exp in exp_list:
                    exp_temp = {
                        each_exp.findNext('span', {"class": "t-14 t-normal t-black--light"}).findNext(
                            'span').get_text().replace('\n', '').strip()  # timeframe
                    }

                    experiences.append(exp_temp)

            # handle the profiles which does not contain experience section
            except AttributeError:
                pass

            # 4 EDUCATION LEVEL AND HISTORY
            educations = []
            try:
                education_div = soup.find('div', {"id": "education"})
                edu_list = education_div.findNext('div').findNext('div', {"class": "pvs-list__outer-container"}).findChild(
                    'ul').findAll('li',
                                  {"class": "artdeco-list__item pvs-list__item--line-separated pvs-list__item--one-column"})

                for each_edu in edu_list:
                    col_edu = each_edu.findNext("a",
                                                {
                                                    "class": "optional-action-target-wrapper display-flex flex-column full-width"})

                    edu_temp = {
                        col_edu.findNext('span', {"class": "t-14 t-normal"}).findNext(
                            'span').get_text().strip(),  # coursename
                    }

                    educations.append(edu_temp)

            # handle the profiles which does not contain education section
            except AttributeError:
                pass

            # 5 lICENSE AND CERTIFICATIONS
            certifications = []
            try:
                cert_div = soup.find('div', {"id": "licenses_and_certifications"})
                cert_list = cert_div.findNext('div').findNext('div', {"class": "pvs-list__outer-container"}).findChild(
                    'ul').findAll('li',
                                  {"class": "artdeco-list__item pvs-list__item--line-separated pvs-list__item--one-column"})

                for cert in cert_list:
                    col_cert = cert.findNext("div", {"class": "display-flex flex-column full-width align-self-center"})
                    cert_temp = {
                        col_cert.findNext('div').findNext('span').findNext('span').text.replace('\n', '').strip()
                        # cert name
                    }

                    certifications.append(cert_temp)

            # handle the profiles which does not contain certification section
            except AttributeError:
                pass

            # 6 SKILLS
            skills = []
            try:
                skills_div = soup.find('div', {"id": "skills"})
                skills_list = skills_div.findNext('div').findNext('div', {"class": "pvs-list__outer-container"}).findChild(
                    'ul').findAll('li',
                                  {"class": "artdeco-list__item pvs-list__item--line-separated pvs-list__item--one-column"})

                for skill in skills_list:
                    col_skill = skill.findNext("a", {"data-field": "skill_card_skill_topic"})
                    skill_temp = {
                        col_skill.findNext('div').findNext('span').findNext('span').text.replace('\n', '').strip()
                        # skills name
                    }
                    skills.append(skill_temp)

            # handle the profiles which does not contain skills section
            except AttributeError:
                pass

            # 7 LANGUAGES
            languages = []
            try:
                Lang_div = soup.find('div', {"id": "languages"})
                lang_list = Lang_div.findNext('div').findNext('div', {"class": "pvs-list__outer-container"}).findChild(
                    'ul').findAll('li',
                                  {"class": "artdeco-list__item pvs-list__item--line-separated pvs-list__item--one-column"})

                for lang in lang_list:
                    lang_temp = {
                        lang.findNext("span", {"class": "mr1 t-bold"}).findNext('span').get_text().strip()  # lang name
                    }
                    languages.append(lang_temp)

            # handle the profiles which does not contain language section
            except AttributeError:
                pass

            data.append({
                "Name": name,
                "Title": title,
                "Location": location,
                "Experiences": experiences,
                "Education": educations,
                "Certifications": certifications,
                "Skills": skills,
                "Languages": languages
            })

    driver.quit()

    return data
```

Here is the coding for data cleaning:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import re
from datetime import datetime
import random

def clean_data(data):
    dfCSV = pd.DataFrame(data)

    # Report missing data
    # dfCSV.isna().sum()

    # cleaning data
    dfCSV['Location'].replace('[]', 'None', inplace=True)
    dfCSV['Experiences'].replace('[]', 'None', inplace=True)
    dfCSV['Education'].replace('[]', 'None', inplace=True)
    dfCSV['Certifications'].replace('[]', 'None', inplace=True)
    dfCSV['Skills'].replace('[]', 'None', inplace=True)
    dfCSV['Languages'].replace('[]', 'None', inplace=True)

    # Convert all string columns to lowercase
    dfCSV = dfCSV.applymap(lambda s: s.lower() if type(s) == str else s)

    df = dfCSV.replace(to_replace=r'[^a-zA-Z\d,\s]', value='', regex=True)

    # convert the dataframe to a list
    data_clean = df.values.tolist()

    print(df)
    return data_clean
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct variable names in the HTML template, use the same variable name to loop through the data and display it.

in display.html replace this line

```
{% for item in data %}
```

with

```
{% for item in cleandata %}
```